# developer.sabre.com user information with full access

Tags: sabre

I want to make sure I have full access to information in my account with sabre.  At this time I am doing a certificate program for Sabre API's.  In the video it shows a much different site than the one I am accessing at this time.

Answer (score 1):

See if on the https://developer.sabre.com/ you can access the "Product Catalog".

- If yes, see in the SesisonCreateRQ service the resources tab is available.
- If yes, locate the wsdl link of this service.
- If yes, then you have access, if not, then you do not have access.